# No last name on Australian PR visa & Indian passport - what should it be on the ticket?

Tags: australia

My passport & Australian Permanent Residency visa have my first name as "Girish" and no last name.

I am about to travel to Australia for the first time. I booked my flight with Sri Lankan Airlines, from Mumbai to Melbourne, and put both my first & last name as "Girish."

Will SL airlines allow me to board with the ticket saying "Girish Girish"? It should be obvious to them, but I do not want any issues. The airlines is asking me to put my name as "Girish LNU" where LNU means last name unknown. But I don't want it to cause problems in immigration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Booking tickets to the US from India with a single name](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173526/booking-tickets-to-the-us-from-india-with-a-single-name)

Answer (score 3):

The background of the issue is - the flight reservation and associated systems are based on very old and rigid standards, which won't accept a blank first/last name. You have to use a work around.

It is the US convention to use FNU and LNU to represent first/last name unknown. Many other countries just duplicates the first name.

Both should work and the Airlines are familiar with the issue. Even if you enter the other way, the agent on checkin desk of airline can fix according to convention they follow.